# A sentence that I don't understand in novel The Three Body Problem

Tags: grammar, sentence

Here is the context from the novel [The Three Body Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three-Body_Problem_(novel)) by Liu Cixin:

> “Have we succeeded?” the princeps asked. “Is that the proton unfolded into two dimensions?”
>
> The science consul replied, “Princeps, it’s still a failure. I just received the report from the accelerator control center. **The unfolding left one too many dimensions in**, and the proton was unfolded into three dimensions.”

The bold part is the one I don't understand. I can't identify the grammatical structure of the sentence as well as the meaning of it.

Comment: The expression  you have to consider us “one too many” ( idiom) which generally refers to alcoholic drinks, but here is idiomatically used meaning  “too many”.

Comment: What’s left is what remains. Left = allowed to remain in this sentence.

Comment: So left means to remain and one too many means too many.

Comment: What does the last word 'in' in 'dimensions in' mean?

Comment: Please reference the quote correctly. Is it from [Liu Cixin's novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three-Body_Problem_(novel))?

Comment: 'Left' does _not_ mean 'to remain'. As Xanne told you, it means '_allowed_ to remain' in this context.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's reply, I got the meaning now.

Comment: @James "... left one too many dimensions in ..." means that the unfolding was insufficiently complete and there were three dimensions in the final result when the experimenters wanted only two. Out of context it is impossible to know how many dimensions  the photon was folded into at the start of the process but the unfolding was supposed to eliminate all but two of them. A very crude analogy would be the unfolding of a piece of origami which is three dimensional to return the sheet of paper to its original two dimensions (except that a sheet of paper has thickness and is, therefore 3-D).

Comment: The *one* in "one too many" is the difference 3 - 2 = 1. One too many does mean too many, but specifically too many by the number one. I can carry two heavy bags in two hands, and three would be *one too many*.

Comment: Thank you all for the very detailed explanation. One last question, is it OK or normal to eliminate the Object part after the phrasal verb "left ... in ..."? I think the complete version of the sentence would be "The unfolding left one too many dimensions in the proton"